# Individual textures for different usage or baked into one

Tags: opengl, direct3d, texture-mapping

Is there any performance gain/loss in baking multiple textures into one combined texture, and just map the UV-coordinates to match the correct texture in each layer of the texturing.

The example below shows three images but they can just as easily be combined into one.

[image]

Comment: The modern way of doing such things is the usage of _array textures_. You should have a look at them.

Answer (score 2):

By combining the textures, you won't have to switch as many textures while rendering, which generally improves performance. However, there's some side effects you'll want to be aware of:

- Adjusting the UV coordinates makes the shader more complicated.
- Mipmapping will make the other texture's values bleed over the edge. Avoiding this basically means [implementing your own mipmapping](http://0fps.net/2013/07/09/texture-atlases-wrapping-and-mip-mapping/), which again adds to shader complexity.
- Combining textures may require padding to bring the texture up to a power-of-two size, wasting memory.
- How much this helps may depend on your graphics card/drivers. Without profiling, there's no way to be sure if using an optimization will help, and it may help more or less on different GPUs.